# Как раскодировать Base64 в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая строка, закодированная в Base64:

```
document.write('0YLQtdGB0YI=');
```

Как сделать так, чтобы она была раскодирована, когда сайт загрузился?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не нужно IE9-, то используйте функцию atob(*string*).
Чтобы сработал ваш пример (с русскими символами) нужно:

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(atob('0YLQtdGB0YI=')));
```

Если нужна поддержка всех браузеров, то придется делать руками. В сети полно решений. Одно из них:

```
var Base64 = {
    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
    encode: function (e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i, s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = Base64._utf8_encode(e);
        while (f < e.length) {
            n = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            r = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            i = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            s = n >> 2;
            o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
            u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
            a = i & 63;
            if (isNaN(r)) {
                u = a = 64
            }
            else if (isNaN(i)) {
                a = 64
            }
            t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
        } return t
    },
    decode: function (e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i;
        var s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
        while (f < e.length) {
            s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            n = s << 2 | o >> 4;
            r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2;
            i = (u & 3) << 6 | a; t = t + String.fromCharCode(n);
            if (u != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(r)
            }
            if (a != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(i)
            }
        }
        t = Base64._utf8_decode(t); return t
    },
    _utf8_encode: function (e) {
        e = e.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var t = "";
        for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
            var r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r)
            }
            else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            }
            else {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            }
        } return t
    },
    _utf8_decode: function (e) {
        var t = "";
        var n = 0;
        var r = c1 = c2 = 0;
        while (n < e.length) {
            r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r);
                n++
            }
            else if (r > 191 && r < 224) {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
                n += 2
            }
            else {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63);
                n += 3
            }
        } return t
    }
}
```

Использовать:

```
Base64.decode("<закодированная строка>");
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо